# vscode: Is there a way to use "go to definition" for functions in "unlinked files"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

For some reason, there's no import/require in this project. I think all the .js files are merged together when running in production. I can't change that, for now.

In my example I can use "go to definition" on `some_class` in file 1 but not on `some_function`.

For some reason this works in Sublime Text. I wish I could use vscode instead.

Any way around this?

file 1:

```js
// doesn't work
some_function();

// works
some_class.something();
```

file 2:

```
some_function = function() {}

class some_class {}
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You probably need to declare it as a variable or function statement.

Comment: `var some_function = function() {}` does seem to work. I would prefer to avoid that since it's a huge codebase, but I'll probably end up doing this if there's no alternative.